# Setting Session Variables and Calculating from other .php files

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I am trying to use php to set session variables on the initial loginPage.php and show up on the paymentPage.php but I am having troubles setting the $_SESSION variables so that it shows up. There is a web page in between the loginPage and the paymentPage and that seems to be tripping me up.

Also, I need to calculate a total of the selected items on the previous page but I am unsure how put a dollar amount with a checkbox that does not show but calculates the total on the paymentPage.

**loginPage.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

?>

<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>Form Login</title>

</head>



<body OnLoad="document.main.username.focus();">

  <table>

    <tr>

      <td colspan="2">

        <h2>Welcome to the Equine Shop!</h2>

        <h4>Please enter a personalized Username, Email Address and Password to continue to our online store</h4>

      </td>

    </tr>

    <!-- create the main form with an input text box named uid and a password text box named mypassword -->

    <form name="main" method="post" action="EquineShop.php">

      <form action="paymentPage.php" method=post>

        <tr>

          <td>Username:</td>

          <td><input type="text" name="username" type="text" size="50"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td>Email Address:</td>

          <td><input type="text" name="emailadd" type="text" size="50"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td>Password:</td>

          <td><input type="password" name="pass" type="text" size="50"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>

        </tr>

  </table>

  </form>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**EquineShop.php**

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Equine Shop Home Page </title>
</head>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    ?>

  <body OnLoad="document.main.username.focus();">

    <form name="main" method="post" action="paymentPage.php">

      <h1 style="text-align:center;">Welcome to the Equine Shop!</h1>
      <table border="5">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Halters</p>
            <p>$25.00</p>
            <p>Built to last, these halters are made of premium quality</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/halters.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://www.valleyvet.com/swatches/35434_S_001_vvs.jpg" width="300" height="250" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Saddle Pads</p>
            <p>$37.00</p>
            <p>You'll love this all purpose saddle pad!</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/saddlepad.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://img.smartpak.com/images/product/20333_Navy.jpg" width="300" height="250" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Girths</p>
            <p>$200.00</p>
            <p>This leather english girth is made of quality leather.</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/girths.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://img.smartpak.com/images/product/highres/14428_Chocolate_Top_silo.jpg?width=460&quality=100" width="300" height="250" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">English Saddles</p>
            <p>$2,200.00</p>
            <p>Soft and comfortable padding with adjustable tree.</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/englishsaddles.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9a/82/6d/9a826d879d8fbea19fe167f267b0d61f.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Bridles</p>
            <p>$150.00</p>
            <p>This plain raised flash bridles delivers complete comfort.</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/bridles.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://www.equestrianweb.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x650/7d70730b2ff80c936b5c98bf27fe5aba/e/c/ec18-geral.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Grooming Materials</p>
            <p>$85.00</p>
            <p>The complete grooming kit!</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/grooming.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/57/db/22/57db225ed12aa5c8009c4861ad6873cb.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Blankets</p>
            <p>$150.00</p>
            <p>1680 denier, turnout, waterproof blanket.</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/blankets.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="http://cdnll.doversaddlery.com/images/xl/0024378.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Sheets</p>
            <p>$124.00</p>
            <p>1200 denier, turnout waterproof sheet.</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/sheets.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="http://cdnll.doversaddlery.com/images/xl/0024280.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Fly Masks</p>
            <p>$30.00</p>
            <p>Keep flys off your horses face this summer!</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/flymasks.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://img.smartpak.com/images/product/highres/21540_Standard_WEars.jpg?width=460" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">First Aid</p>
            <p>$100.00</p>
            <p>The complete first aid kit for your horse</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/firstaid.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="http://cdnll.doversaddlery.com/images/xl/0011304.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Spurs</p>
            <p>$45.00</p>
            <p>These soft touch spurs are great for sensitive horses</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/spurs.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://img.smartpak.com/images/product/300x300/19089.jpg?width=224&quality=100" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p style="font-size:24px;">Whips</p>
            <p>$50.00</p>
            <p>Dressage whips for optimum riding</p>
            <p><a href="http://localhost/week2/whips.html">Click for more details!</a></p>
            <p><img src="https://ii.bigdweb.com/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?FIF=/images/bigdweb/source/3011f_c1105.tif&qlt=75&wid=225&cvt=jpeg" width="300" height="300" /></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>


      <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> Order Form</b></p>
      First Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br> Street Address:<br>
      <input type="text" name="street"><br> City:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="city"><br> State:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="state"><br> Zip:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
      <br>

      <table>
        Product:
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Halter">Halter</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="SaddlePad">Saddle Pad</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Girth">Girth</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Saddle">English Saddle</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Bridle">Bridle</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Grooming">Grooming Material </td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Blanket">Blanket</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="FirstAid">First Aid</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="spur">Spur</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="tack[]" value="Whip">Whip</td>
          <td>Quantity: <select name="quantity">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <br><input type="submit" value="Proceed to Checkout" />

    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**paymentPage.php**

```
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>Equine Shop Payment Form</title>

</head>

<body>

    <?php 

        // Display in a table      

       echo "<h1> Equine Shop Payment Form </h1>";

       echo "<table border='1'>";

       echo "<tr>

             <th>User Name</th>

             <th>E-mail Address</th>

             </tr>";

       echo "<tr>

             <td>$_SESSION['username']</td>

             <td>$_SESSION['emailadd']</td>

             </tr>";

       echo "</table><br><br>";      

?>



    <?php

    $selected = $_POST['tack'];

        if(empty($selected)){

            echo("You didn't select any products!");

        } else {

            $checked = count($selected);

            echo("<b>Shopping Cart: </b><br><br>");

            for($i = 0; $i < $checked; $i++) {

                echo($selected[$i] . "<br>");



            }

        }

?>

      <br><br>

      <?php

    echo "<b>Total: </b>"

?>



        <form>

          <br><br>Credit Card Type:<br>

          <input type="radio" name="ccard" <?php if (isset($ccard) && $ccard=="visa" ) echo "checked";?> value="visa">Visa

          <br>

          <input type="radio" name="ccard" <?php if (isset($ccard) && $ccard=="master" ) echo "checked";?> value="master">MasterCard

          <br>

          <input type="radio" name="ccard" <?php if (isset($ccard) && $ccard=="discover" ) echo "checked";?> value="discover">Discover

          <br>

          <input type="radio" name="ccard" <?php if (isset($ccard) && $ccard=="amex" ) echo "checked";?> value="amex">American Express<br>

        </form>

        <br> Card Number:<br>

        <input type="text" name="card" maxlength="16">

        <br> Exp Date:<br>

        <input type="text" name="exp" maxlength="4">

        <br> Security Number:<br>

        <input type="text" name="secnum" maxlength="3">

        <br>



        <form action="">

          Comments:<br>

          <input type="text" name="comments" maxlength="300"><br>

        </form>



        <form name="main" method="post" action="thankYou.php">

          <input type="submit" value="Submit Order">

        </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**thankYou.php**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> Thank You for your Purchase! </title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
    echo "<b>Thank you for your Purchase!</b>"
?>
    <br>
    <?php 
    echo "Your order will be processed immediatley and arrive within 7 - 10 business days"
?>

    <br><br>
    <form name="main" method="post" action="loginPage.php">
      <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
      <?php
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    ?>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look I really looked through your code and I don't know if there's something missing but I doesn't make too much sense for me. Anyway if it works for you it's fine.

Here's a Typo that I found:

paymentPage.php

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $_SESSION['username'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $_SESSION['emailadd'] . "</td>
     </tr>";
```

And for your calculation.. I don't know man. You made the dom a little bit to static to get these values foreach product or whatever. The best thing you can do is to give every element a unique Id oder class and than validate it via JS to see if it got checkt or not. There's still a long way for you.. But remember we don't write your code.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty, I am very new to this as I have never worked with HTML or PHP before. I will take your suggestions and see what I can come up with! I wasn't expecting you to give me code, just some pointers on what I need to improve and what you think of my problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to ask a question and to explain your problem.

Any page which is accessing the session *must*(1) start with a PHP block containing `session_start()`. Only 1 of the the 4 scripts you've shown us does this.

1) Not strictly true - but a discussion of the exceptions is too complex to go into here

Comment: Ok, so every single page needs to contain session_start() in order for the variables to be passed to other pages? I will work on that to correct my issue. I guess my questions were 1) why are my variables not being passed to the other pages and 2) in word form, how should I go about getting a total dollar amount on the paymentPage.php from the EquineShop.php page. Not looking for code, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another problem i found is on your thankyou page:

```
<form name="main" method="post" action="loginPage.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
  <?php
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
?>
</form>
```

What I think you are trying to do: You are trying to make a form that removes all your session variables when you click the submit button.

What you are actually doing:

You are rendering a form that on submit wil send a POST to `loginPage.php`. and while you are building this form on the server you are also already unsetting the Session variables. As the code above equals the code i show you here below:

```
<?php //deleting session state
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
 //now lets output some html, being a form:
?>    
<form name="main" method="post" action="loginPage.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
</form>
```